# Element hidden even when opacity is 1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a flex-box aligned button that toggle the html content on my page. I would like to reuse the button to re-enable the html content.
Toggling visibility works but as soon as I add opacity to have css-transitions, my button also disappears. Inspecting the element shows that the element still has an opacity of 1.

The element is still there, but invisible. Removing opacity rules, results in intended behavior without transitions.

Here is an MRE

```html
<div id='content'>
<i id='toggle' class='fa fa-toggle-off'></i>
<p>
This is the main content!
</p>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#content{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hide{
  visibility: hidden !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

#toggle{
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```js
let content = document.getElementById('content');

document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.classList.contains('fa-toggle-off')){
        content.classList.add('hide');
        this.classList.remove('fa-toggle-off');
        this.classList.add('fa-toggle-on');
    } else {
        content.classList.remove('hide');
        this.classList.remove('fa-toggle-on');
        this.classList.add('fa-toggle-off');
    }
});
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cains/38v9q7cn/7/)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correct. But inside your JS if condition, you are adding the `.hide` class to your content container. `content.classList.add('hide');` This results in your whole content being hidden

Comment: If you really just want to hide the content but not the toggle itself, try to change the first JS line like following `let content = document.querySelector('#content p');`

Comment: Yes that is intentional. I want to hide all of html content which is inside my content div. But there is a button inside that I want to stay visible. For additional context, All of the html content inside div is being drawn over a THREEjs Scene, and the html content is the HUD.

Comment: @Hoargarth That would work for the MRE, but my content is a bit nested. As the button is part of the navbar which is inside content.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without having the toggle outside your content container. As soos as the `.content` is hidden, you can not make #toggle not visible again.

Comment: try removing opacity rules from my code @Hoargarth. It definitely is possible, I need opacity for the transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since you don't want or cant move out the toggle I see only one option to do it.
Don't hide the content itself, but everything inside the content container but the #toggle button.

Here's the CSS for it:

```
#content *:not(#toggle){
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hide > *:not(#toggle){
  visibility: hidden !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

- `>` selects all children
- `*` we don't care about the element type from the children, just sake everything
- `:not(#toggle)` apply styles to everything that's not from ID toggle

So as a sentence: Select all children from .hide except the element with #toggle as ID.

You could leave out the children selector `>` but I would keep it for performance, since without it you would also select all children from children and so on.

And an updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fx7rp5bm/

Comment: this is redundant as there are still no transitions. I can achieve this by not having opacity at all.

Comment: @Blaine fix for transition is above, also fiddle is updated to do transitions

Comment: Thanks, feels very hacky but it works! 
```
#content > *:not(.top),
#content > .top > *:not(.menu),
#content > .top > .search > *:not(#toggle)
``` was very weird to write.

Comment: Yes, I feel with you :P At this level of nesting you may consider using a css preprocessor like `less` or `sass`. This could make it shorter and more easy to read. I'll just leave this link here, maybe it's something for you: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-preprocessor/info

Comment: I had sass in mind but I would prefer to stick to css only for this project. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you add **.hide class opacity to 5 or anything but 0 and 1**, the transition will work. And the button will remain in view.

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#content{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hide{
  visibility: hidden !important;
  opacity: 2 !important;
}

#toggle{
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the same issue I had without using opacity. Visibility cannot have transition animations. Using this also removes the transitions.

Comment: Also https://jsfiddle.net/Cains/38v9q7cn/11/ shows to me that this doesn't work either. (The html elements are entirely hidden.)

Comment: I just changed the .hide class opacity to 5, it is working fine without losing transition animations. You just have to give opacity anything but 1 and 0 to make animation work.

Comment: Could you update your code to reflect that change? As I cant seem to achieve the same.